# Multi-stage build cannot run ENTRYPOINT from previous stage - no such file or directory

Tags: docker, go, google-cloud-platform, dockerfile

I have the sub project that was made by golang.

I want to build it into the image and upload to the Artifact Refistry to the google cloud.

So I can use this image to create job and run it on the google cloud.

The structure of project is like this:

```
├ application
│
├ hello
│ └ firstJob
│    └ main.go
│
├ go.mod
│
├ go.sum
│
└ main.go
```

The content of go.mod is very simple, like this as below:

```
module github.com/demo/first-sub-project
go 1.19
```

And the main.go that in the firstJob folder will refer go.mod that in the root.

The content of hello/firstJob/main.go like this as below:

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/caarlos0/env"
    "github.com/demo/first-sub-project/application"
)

func main() {
    cfg := application.Config{}
    err := env.Parse(&cfg)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("parse config error: %v", err)
    }
    log.Println("Finish")
}
```

I have the docker file as follows:

```
# refer https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-run-hello/blob/master/placeholder.dockerfile
FROM golang:1.19-buster as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download
COPY . ./
RUN go build -o job github.com/demo/first-sub-project/hello/firstJob

FROM alpine:3
RUN apk add --no-cache ca-certificates
COPY --from=builder /app/job /job
ENV TZ=Asia/Tokyo
ENTRYPOINT ["/job"]
```

I can build and push image container to the google cloud and create job on the google cloud successfully.

But when I run the job, it will show error message as below:

**standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: no such file or directory**

And it will working fine if I change my hello/firstJob/main.go like this as below:

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/caarlos0/env"
)

type Config struct {
    Port int
}

func main() {
    cfg := Config{}
    err := env.Parse(&cfg)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("parse config error: %v", err)
    }
    log.Println("Finish")
}
```

It seems like that it can not find the package path in the previous stage when run ENTRYPOINT in the dockerfile.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I've seen similar problems mixing a Debian build stage and an Alpine final stage, or _vice versa_.  Does changing the build stage to be `FROM golang:1.19-alpine` improve things?

Comment: @DavidMaze OMG, you saved my day! It work after I chanage `FROM golang:1.19-buster` to `FROM golang:1.19-alpine`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue solved!

Like David Maze said, the problem is the different version of stage.

The original docker file as follows:

```
FROM golang:1.19-buster as builder
...

FROM alpine:3
...
```

I try to use different stages to build project and run project.

And the problem was solved after I change Dockerfile to use same stage to build project and run project.

```
FROM golang:1.19-alpine as builder
...

FROM alpine:3
...
```